# How can I assign IPv6 addresses based on existing IPv4 addresses?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, ipv6

I have several hundred Server 2008 R2 machines with static IPv4 addresses.  I'd like to enable IPv6 on each interface, and then automatically assign IPv6 addresses to them based on their existing IPv4 addresses.  Is there a good way to do this?

I wrote a power shell script that does this, but it uses "get-netadapter" and the like, so it will only work on my server 2012 R2 machines.

Comment: so, um... any reason not to use DHCPv6?

Comment: Yeah, we can't in this environment, everything has to be statically addressed.

Comment: You know about DHCP Reservations, right?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it's easier to do things like this from a central management tool, rather than from the hammers and nails of individual machine management.

Comment: I know about DHCP reservations, but I can't use them here. I have to have the IPv6 addresses statically assigned.

Comment: And even if I did use DHCPv6, what is the best way to make sure that ipv6 is enabled on each interface and set to DHCP?

Comment: That would require configuration management of each machine, yes. Again, better centralized than individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is more than one way to skin a cat.

- You could rewrite your script to use older commands that are compatible with previous versions of PowerShell. (A WMI call to the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was the typical way to do this.)
- You could create a new script [using the `netsh` command](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html), which is the pre-PowerShell method of manipulating network settings via a CLI.
- [You could install Windows Management Framework 4 (and PowerShell along with it) on your Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 machines](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx) to make your existing script and the `get-netadapter` cmdlet work.

Having said that, especially with IPv6, static assignments and manually hunting through the address space is exponentially more painful and involved than it is with IPv4, so I'll repeat the advice of using DHCP to do this.  Assigning IP address is the whole reason DHCP exists, after all.

Comment: I tried installing powershell 4.0 on a few server 2008 r2 machines, but they still wont support the get-netadapter command.  Other than that, this is all spot on, thank you so much.  I will have to change the script to use the netsh command, and convince some folks here that DHCP is the way to go.  Some people are just old school.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [unsupported tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bernhard_frank/archive/2011/08/22/how-to-turn-on-ipv6-from-the-cmd-line-script.aspx) that can turn on IPv6 from the command line called [NVSPbind](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/01/25/announcing-nvspbind.aspx).  There are probably others as well.  Or you could use [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770948(v=ws.10).aspx), which is probably the path of least resistance.

[This article](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/supporting-ipv6-your-windows-server-2008-environment) might help.  It has a lot of handy netsh commands (`netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state enabled`, etc.), that you could include in a script.

Good luck!